# Azure Cloud Services - Migration to Extended Support - .cer certificates

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services, x509certificate2

I have some `.cer` certificates (only public key) in my classic cloud service. I don't quite understand how am I supposed to migrate those to extended support.

`.pfx` certificates, I can pre-upload to Key Vault before executing `New-AzCloudService` with command `az keyvault certificate import`. That command does not work with `.cer` (it expects private key inside certificate).

If I don't upload the certificate, `New-AzCloudService` understandably fails because it can't find the certificate mentioned in `.cscfg`.

Answer (score 0):

.CER files are public keys that do not contain secrets, by definition, so protected KeyVault storage is not generally required. This is an unfortunate compatibility break between the classic offering and the modern one (though I'd argue that the modern approach is the more sensible one. :)).

I also do not see any automated handling or documented workarounds for this scenario, so unfortunately it seems that some manual workaround is required for migration. :(

In your situation, I'd look into making these modifications to the current cloud service:

1. Either embed the public key files in the package as resource files that will be automatically copied to the vm or make them available in some storage account, depending on your requirements around key changes.
2. Create a [StartupTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common) to install the public keys in appropriate locations when the service starts up.

StartupTasks are defined in the CSDEF and the same CSPKG files are used before and after migration, so these modifications should migrate transparently.